# git history of fetches

Tags: git

Is there any way to see history of execution `git fetch` (update from remote) command?
For example:
01 Jan fetched from sha: 01abcdf to sha: bdf412

I have regression in my code and I know time when this regression is not present.
My git graph is straight, so I thought, if will know my fetch history I can easily detect commit that brings this regression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to detect where a regression came from, use `git bisect`

git bisect does a dichotomy search, you have to specify a good and a bad hash, it will then jump to revisions and ask you if the commit is good or bad.

```
git bisect start
git bisect good SOME_HASH
git bisect bad SOME_OTHER_HASH
# Git will jump to a revision and let you test
git bisect good # Or bad, depending on if the bug is still here
git bisect bad ...
# And so on
```

Comment: +1. Definitely have a read of the [man pages](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html). Git-bisect saves so much time, especially if you are able to use `git bisect run command` with formalized tests.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such log (for fetching) to my knowledge, but there are other ways to find when the bug was introduced.

1. Use [git rev-list](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html) to see which commits you actually checked out (this is different than simply fetching).
2. If that does not help, use [git bisect](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html), which is a more powerful and complicated tool. It will make it easier to go through the commits, until you find the one that is broken.